# Custom Menu url is Empty

Tags: menus

I added a new menu using this code:

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => 'Custom menu',
            'menu-item-url' => 'http://mylink.com',         
            'menu-item-db-id' => 0,
            'menu-item-object' => 'custom',
            'menu-item-parent-id' => 328,
            'menu-item-type' => 'Custom',           
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',)
        );
```

That code generates a menu the way I wanted. But the link is totally empty.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu type is:

```
'menu-item-type' => 'Custom',
```

But if we look in `wp_update_nav_menu_item`:

```
if ( 'custom' != $args['menu-item-type'] ) {
```

`custom != Custom`, so your URL gets stripped